# Cannot link external library using CMake, either library not found or undefined user reference

Tags: c++, cmake, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have been given a custom C++ library which I need for some simulations that I'm writing, and have been told I should build this using CMake (I should note I have never used CMake before). I am trying to write a CMakeLists.txt file so that I can call functions from this library. No matter what method I seem to try it does not want to link, however it is fine with including all of the relevant header files now.

For context on the step up, I have Ubuntu on WSL but the library I need is located on an external hard drive, I can change the structure of this if this is where the issues lie.

On WSL I have: project folder (where CMakeLists.txt is) -> subdir called Build (where I'm trying to build it).

The library structure is: D://some_path/Positioner->Poslib (the header files I need are here)
Data
Configure
ect.
The library also has a build folder under Positioner, with the same subdirectory names that each include a libname.a file.

I am trying to link to most of the library subdirectories to avoid dependency issues. The functions I'm trying to call all use the namespace Pos if that's relevant.

Below is my CMakeLists.txt setup (I have a lot of stuff I've tested commented out sorry):

```
project(wrapDelta)

if(NOT CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE)
    set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release)
endif()

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
#set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED True)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)

# Various compiler warnings from external include files are disabled with
# GCC pragmas but these are not supported before gcc version 6.
if (${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_VERSION} VERSION_GREATER 6)
    add_compile_options(-Wall -pedantic-errors -Wextra -Werror)
else()
    add_compile_options(-Wall -pedantic-errors -Wextra -Werror
        -Wno-unused-variable -Wno-unused-parameter
        -Wno-maybe-uninitialized)
endif()

set(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH_USE_LINK_PATH TRUE)

# Default path for finding the SOFA library
set(SOFA_DIR /home/name/sofa/20210512/c/src) 

#Setting directories for different positioner software libraries
set(POSLIB_DIR ${/mnt/d/pos/positioner/poslib/})
set(DATA_DIR ${/mnt/d/pos/positioner/data})
set(PLATE_GEN_DIR ${/mnt/d/pos/positioner/plate_gen})
set(CONFIGURE_DIR ${/mnt/d/pos/positioner/configure})
set(LIFU_DIR ${/mnt/d/pos/positioner/lifu_configure})


set(BOOST_INCLUDEDIR $ENV{/home/name/boost_1_77_0/boost})
set(BOOST_LIBRARYDIR $ENV{/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu})
set(boost_filesystem_DIR /mnt/c/Program Files/boost/boost_1_77_0/stage/lib/cmake/boost_filesystem-1.77.0)


find_package(Boost 1.6 REQUIRED CONFIG
    COMPONENTS program_options system filesystem log unit_test_framework
)


find_library(SOFA t_sofa_c REQUIRED PATHS ${SOFA_DIR})          #libsofa_c.a REQUIRED PATHS /home/name/starlink/starlink/thirdparty/sofa/sofa/src)#/lib at the end
find_package(Qt5 5.9.5 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Core Widgets Xml PrintSupport Gui)

#find_library(LIB_POSLIB NAMES poslib libposlib.a REQUIRED PATHS ${POSLIB_DIR} NO_DEFAULT_PATH)

include_directories(/home/name/sofa/20210512/c/src) #/home/name/starlink/starlink/thirdparty/sofa/sofa/src)
include_directories(/mnt/d/pos/positioner/poslib)
include_directories(/mnt/d/pos/positioner/data)
include_directories(/mnt/d/pos/positioner/plate_gen)
include_directories(/mnt/d/pos/positioner/configure)
include_directories(/mnt/d/pos/positioner/lifu_configure)


include_directories(/mnt/d/pos/positioner/build/poslib)
include_directories(/mnt/d/pos/positioner/build/data)
include_directories(/mnt/d/pos/positioner/build/plate_gen)
include_directories(/mnt/d/pos/positioner/build/configure)
include_directories(/mnt/d/pos/positioner/build/lifu_configure)
include_directories(/mnt/d/pos/positioner/build/poslib)

include_directories(${Qt5Core_INCLUDE_DIRS})
include_directories(${Qt5Widgets_INCLUDE_DIRS})
include_directories(${Qt5Xml_INCLUDE_DIRS})
include_directories(${Qt5PrintSupport_INCLUDE_DIRS})
include_directories(${Qt5Gui_INCLUDE_DIRS})

link_directories(/home/name/sofa/20210512/c/src/) #/home/name/starlink/starlink/thirdparty/sofa/sofa/src)
link_directories("/mnt/d/pos/positioner/poslib/")
link_directories("/mnt/d/pos/positioner/data/")
link_directories("/mnt/d/pos/positioner/plate_gen/")
link_directories("/mnt/d/pos/positioner/configure/")
link_directories("/mnt/d/pos/positioner/lifu_configure/")

link_directories("/mnt/d/pos/positioner/build/poslib/")
link_directories("/mnt/d/pos/positioner/build/data/")
link_directories("/mnt/d/pos/positioner/build/plate_gen/")
link_directories("/mnt/d/pos/positioner/build/configure/")
link_directories("/mnt/d/pos/positioner/build/lifu_configure/")

file(GLOB poslib_Sources RELATIVE "/mnt/d/pos/positioner/poslib/" "*.cpp")
file(GLOB poslib_h_Sources RELATIVE "/mnt/d/pos/positioner/poslib/" "*.h")

add_executable(delta_wrap_test Delta_wrap_test.cpp ${poslib_Sources} ${poslib_h_Sources})

qt5_use_modules(delta_wrap_test Core Xml Gui Widgets PrintSupport)

add_library(python_delta SHARED Delta_wrap_test.cpp)


add_library(data STATIC IMPORTED GLOBAL)
set_target_properties(data PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION $ENV{/mnt/d/pos/positioner/build/data}/libconfig_files_resource.a)

add_library(plate_gen STATIC IMPORTED GLOBAL)
set_target_properties(plate_gen PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION $ENV{/mnt/d/pos/positioner/plate_gen}/libplate_files_resource.a)

add_library(configure SHARED IMPORTED GLOBAL)
set_target_properties(configure PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION $ENV{/mnt/d/pos/positioner/configure}/configure.cpp) #configure

add_library(lifu SHARED IMPORTED GLOBAL)
set_target_properties(lifu PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION $ENV{/mnt/d/pos/positioner/lifu_configure}/lifu_configure.cpp) #lifu_configure

add_library(sofa STATIC IMPORTED GLOBAL)
set_target_properties(sofa PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION $ENV{/home/name/sofa/20210512/c/src}/libsofa.a)


add_library(poslib STATIC IMPORTED GLOBAL)

set_target_properties(poslib PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION "/mnt/d/pos/positioner/build/poslib/")#$ENV{/mnt/d/pos/positioner/build/poslib}/libposlib.a)


#target_link_libraries(delta_wrap_test ${/mnt/d/pos/positioner/data})
#target_link_libraries(delta_wrap_test ${/mnt/d/pos/positioner/plate_gen})
#target_link_libraries(delta_wrap_test ${/mnt/d/pos/positioner/configure})
#target_link_libraries(delta_wrap_test ${/mnt/d/pos/positioner/lifu_configure})
#target_link_libraries(delta_wrap_test ${/mnt/d/pos/positioner/poslib})

#target_link_libraries(${delta_wrap_test} ${/home/name/sofa/20210512/c/src})

target_link_libraries(delta_wrap_test
    ${sofa}
    ${Boost_LIBRARIES}
    Qt5::Core
    Qt5::Widgets
    Qt5::Xml
    Qt5::PrintSupport
    Qt5::Gui
    Threads::Threads
    
)

#${LIB_POSLIB}
```

Currently this is the error message I am getting:

```
Scanning dependencies of target delta_wrap_test_autogen
[ 12%] Automatic MOC for target delta_wrap_test
[ 12%] Built target delta_wrap_test_autogen
Scanning dependencies of target delta_wrap_test
[ 25%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/delta_wrap_test.dir/Delta_wrap_test.cpp.o
[ 37%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/delta_wrap_test.dir/delta_wrap_test_autogen/mocs_compilation.cpp.o
[ 50%] Linking CXX executable delta_wrap_test
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
CMakeFiles/delta_wrap_test.dir/Delta_wrap_test.cpp.o: In function `Delta_wrap_test::define(QString)':
Delta_wrap_test.cpp:(.text+0xa7): undefined reference to `pos::loadXmlFile(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
CMakeFiles/delta_wrap_test.dir/Delta_wrap_test.cpp.o: In function `Delta_wrap_test::applyMove()':
Delta_wrap_test.cpp:(.text+0x1d4): undefined reference to `pos::PhysicalPlate::parkFibre(int, bool)'
Delta_wrap_test.cpp:(.text+0x1e1): undefined reference to `pos::Plate::moveFibre(int, bool)'
Delta_wrap_test.cpp:(.text+0x1fd): undefined reference to `pos::Delta::dumpFibre(unsigned int) const'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/delta_wrap_test.dir/build.make:134: recipe for target 'delta_wrap_test' failed
make[2]: *** [delta_wrap_test] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/delta_wrap_test.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/delta_wrap_test.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Any help/advice would be really appreciated, as at this stage I am just running out of ideas.

Comment: Setting `set(POSLIB_DIR ${/mnt/d/pos/positioner/poslib/})` is definitely **wrong**: a construction `${..}` extracts value of a **variable**, but `/mnt/d/pos/positioner/poslib/` is a **path**. Instead, try `set(POSLIB_DIR "/mnt/d/pos/positioner/poslib/")`.

Comment: I did that and sadly it still couldn't find the library. I also tried removing the LIB_POSLIB part entirely and using poslib in target_link_directory again and get the same error as this one.

Comment: Does a source of `delta_wrap_test` contain a definition of a `main` function with the appropriate signature? Are the missing functions defined in a source file (unless generated by moc)? Btw: the if testing for the gcc version is wrong, since version 6 is not greater than 6; furthermore repeated `add_compile_options` commands are allowed: `add_compile_options(-Wall -pedantic-errors -Wextra -Werror) if (${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_VERSION} VERSION_LESS 6) add_compile_options(-Wno-unused-variable -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-maybe-uninitialized) endif()`

Comment: Moreover commands like `include_directories(${Qt5Gui_INCLUDE_DIRS})` are unnecessary, if you link `Qt5::Gui` to the target using these includes; the imported target `Qt5::Gui` provides information automatically making the relevant include directories available to the linking target.

Comment: delta_wrap_test is currently just a class that I'm trying to write, so there isn't any instance of ``` main{}```. The missing functions are defined in the header and source files within poslib.

Answer (score 0):

So I have fixed this problem now using

```
target_link_libraries(delta_wrap_test "/mnt/d/pos/positioner/build/poslib/libposlib.a")
```

However, I have now realised the further errors that I get from this are from the libposlib.a library depending on the Sofa library I'm also linking too, so I believe that I need to make a new static library linking those before this will work. Any advice on linking static libraries together from different directories would be welcome.

#####Update####
Here is the final CMake final that was able to compile my code without errors:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
cmake_policy(SET CMP0060 NEW)

project(wrapDelta)

if(NOT CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE)
    set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release)
endif()

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
#set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
#set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED True)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(LINUX TRUE)

# Various compiler warnings from external include files are disabled with
# GCC pragmas but these are not supported before gcc version 6.
if (${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_VERSION} VERSION_GREATER 6)
    add_compile_options( -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lboost_system-Wall -pedantic-errors -Wextra -Werror)
else()
    add_compile_options( -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lboost_system -Wall -pedantic-errors -Wextra -Werror
        -Wno-unused-variable -Wno-unused-parameter
        -Wno-maybe-uninitialized -DBoost_USE_STATIC_LIBS=ON)
endif()

#set(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH_USE_LINK_PATH TRUE)

#set(Boost_NO_BOOST_CMAKE TRUE)
#set(Boost_NO_SYSTEM_PATHS TRUE)
#set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS TRUE)
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS OFF) 
#set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED ON)  
#set(Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME OFF) 
#set(Boost_NO_SYSTEM_PATHS TRUE)
SET(Boost_DEBUG ON)

#set( BOOST_ROOT "" CACHE PATH /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ )
#set( Boost_NO_SYSTEM_PATHS on CACHE BOOL "Do not search system for Boost" )

# Default path for finding the SOFA library
set(SOFA_DIR /home/name/sofa/20210512/c/src/) 

#Setting directories for different positioner software libraries

set(POSLIB_DIR /mnt/d/pos/positioner/build/poslib/) #/mnt/d/pos/positioner/poslib/)
set(DATA_DIR "mnt/d/pos/positioner/data")
set(PLATE_GEN_DIR "/mnt/d/pos/positioner/plate_gen")
set(CONFIGURE_DIR "/mnt/d/pos/positioner/configure")
set(LIFU_DIR "/mnt/d/pos/positioner/lifu_configure")

#set(Boost_ROOT /usr/include/boost/)
#set(Boost_DIR /usr/include/boost/)
#set(BOOST_INCLUDEDIR /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/)
#set(BOOST_LIBRARYDIR /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/)
#set(boost_filesystem_DIR /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/)

###testing library inclusion
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/Modules/")
set(LIBS ${/usr/lib/cmake/Boost-1.77.0/})


find_package(Boost 1.65 REQUIRED CONFIG
    COMPONENTS filesystem program_options log unit_test_framework system PATHS ${BOOST_ROOT}) 
#EXACT
IF (Boost_FOUND)
    INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(SYSTEM ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR})
    link_directories (${BOOST_LIBRARYDIR})
ENDIF()

find_library(LIB_POSLIB NAMES poslib REQUIRED PATHS ${POSLIB_DIR})

####keep the library name as Sofa not SOFA
find_library(Sofa libsofa_c.a REQUIRED PATHS ${SOFA_DIR})
find_package(Qt5 5.9.5 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Core Widgets Xml PrintSupport Gui)

include_directories("/home/name/sofa/20210512/c/src/") 
include_directories("/mnt/d/pos/positioner/poslib/")
include_directories("/mnt/d/pos/positioner/data/")
include_directories("/mnt/d/pos/positioner/plate_gen/")
include_directories("/mnt/d/pos/positioner/configure/")
include_directories("/mnt/d/pos/positioner/lifu_configure/")


include_directories("/mnt/d/pos/positioner/build/poslib/")
include_directories("/mnt/d/pos/positioner/build/data/")
include_directories("/mnt/d/pos/positioner/build/plate_gen/")
include_directories("/mnt/d/pos/positioner/build/configure/")
include_directories("/mnt/d/pos/positioner/build/lifu_configure/")
include_directories("/mnt/d/pos/positioner/build/poslib/")

include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
include_directories(${Qt5Widgets_INCLUDE_DIRS})
include_directories(${Qt5Core_INCLUDE_DIRS})
include_directories(${Qt5Xml_INCLUDE_DIRS})
include_directories(${Qt5PrintSupport_INCLUDE_DIRS})
include_directories(${Qt5Gui_INCLUDE_DIRS})

link_directories("/home/sarah/sofa/20210512/c/src/") 
link_directories("/mnt/d/pos/positioner/poslib/")
link_directories("/mnt/d/pos/positioner/data/")
link_directories("/mnt/d/pos/positioner/plate_gen/")
link_directories("/mnt/d/pos/positioner/configure/")
link_directories("/mnt/d/pos/positioner/lifu_configure/")

link_directories("/mnt/d/pos/positioner/build/poslib/")
link_directories("/mnt/d/pos/positioner/build/data/")
link_directories("/mnt/d/pos/positioner/build/plate_gen/")
link_directories("/mnt/d/pos/positioner/build/configure/")
link_directories("/mnt/d/pos/positioner/build/lifu_configure/")

link_directories(${Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS})


add_executable(delta_wrap_test Delta_wrap_test.cpp ${poslib_Sources} ${poslib_h_Sources})

qt5_use_modules(delta_wrap_test Core Xml Gui Widgets PrintSupport)

add_library(python_delta SHARED Delta_wrap_test.cpp)


target_link_libraries(delta_wrap_test 
    ${LIB_POSLIB}
    ${Sofa}
    boost_filesystem
    boost_system
    ${Boost_LIBRARIES}
    Boost::system
    Boost::thread  
    Qt5::Core
    Qt5::Widgets
    Qt5::Xml
    Qt5::PrintSupport
    Qt5::Gui
    Threads::Threads  
    
)
```